# Searching from home page using DataTables

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables

I have an index page that uses the jQuery DataTables plugin to filter the data in the index. On my home page I have a search form.  When this form gets submitted I want to take users to the index page with the DataTables search field filled in with the value they entered on the home page. Right now I am passing the search value in through the index controller.

How do I go about setting the DataTables search field using the value I passed into the index view?

Are there better ways of performing a DataTables search from another page?

I am using Rails 3.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the oSearch initialisation parameter ( http://datatables.net/ref#oSearch ) to initialise the DataTable with an initial search value, or use the fnFilter API method to apply a search at any other point (just after initialisation for example).